# Swift: Textfield only with numbers and "."

Tags: swift

is there a way to allow only double values in a textfield?
I want to save a money value in it like 1.50 €.

For saving the value, i remove the euro sign like this:

```
    var moneyValue: String = amountField.text
    var stringLength = countElements(moneyValue)
    var substringIndex = stringLength - 2
    var finishedValue: String =  moneyValue.substringToIndex(advance(moneyValue.startIndex, substringIndex))
```

Or is there another solution available?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Why dont you just set the UIKeyboardType to UIKeyboardTypeNumberPad?

Comment: Maybe because you can add numbers like 1.2.3.4 ?

Comment: Exactly, thats my problem. But this i can avoid with an if clause, or?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have written one function, just check if it works for you:

```
 func formatAsPrice(priceString: NSString) -> NSString {

    var price: NSNumber = NSNumber(Double: priceString.doubleValue) ;

    var formatter = NSNumberFormatter()
    formatter.numberStyle = .CurrencyStyle
    formatter.stringFromNumber(price)

    formatter.locale = NSLocale(localeIdentifier: "YOUR_Locale")
    var priceNumber : NSString = formatter.stringFromNumber(price)!

    return priceNumber

}
```

Comment: I put the money value with the help of UIstepper. And the stepValue = 0.5. Now the function rounds up to the higher value (10.50 --> 11.00) Do you know why?

Comment: That was happening because I was taking the Int value from `priceString`, edited the answer

Answer (score 0):

There are two solutions. One is to use `NSNumberFormatter` and trying to decode the text value. The second is to use `NSRegularExpression` and match `"^[+-]?\\d*(\\.\\d{0,2})?$"`. The latter prevents entering amounts like 1.234 if you just want legal cent values. Of course you can check if the value from `NSNumberFormatter` is legal with a litte arithmetic.